# Immerable property getting removed when compiling typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutability, immer.js

Suppose I have the following classes:

```js
export class Greeting {
    [immerable] = true; // Needed for immer drafting to work properly
    // see https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/complex-objects
    public hello: string = 'world';
}

export class Message {
    [immerable] = true;
    public msg: Greeting = new Greeting();
}
```

Immer drafting works, as I can check by running the following code:

```js
const message: Message = new Message();
const newMessage = produce(message, draft => {
    draft.msg.hello = "aaa";
});
console.log(message === newMessage); // logs false, as it should because message doesn't get mutated
console.log(message.msg.hello === "world"); // logs true for the same reason
```

However, moving these classes to a different module that gets imported into the current module means immer no longer works: the first statement logs true and the second false, which means that the original `message` does get mutated; this is what happens without the `[immerable] = true` line. I suspect it has something to do with how the typescript is compiled. Here is the tsconfig for the sub-module (the one I moved the classes to):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

Thus classes are imported from the `/lib` directory which contains generated `.js` and `.d.ts` files. Here are what the two above classes get compiled to:

```js
// .d.ts:
export declare class Greeting {
    [immerable]: boolean;
    hello: string;
}
export declare class Message {
    [immerable]: boolean;
    msg: Greeting;
}

// .js:
var Greeting = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Greeting() {
        this[_a] = true;
        this.hello = 'world';
    }
    return Greeting;
}());
exports.Greeting = Greeting;
_a = immer_1.immerable;
var Message = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Message() {
        this[_b] = true;
        this.msg = new Greeting();
    }
    return Message;
}());
exports.Message = Message;
_b = immer_1.immerable;
```

It seems that the line does get preserved, but for some reason immer drafting does not work. [Here are the docs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/complex-objects) for `immerable`. I am very confused - I think this is just an issue of me not having enough typescript knowledge to get this working.